# How to Order one list by the index values stored in another list

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a `BigDecimal` `List` such as:

```
[50.0,26.2,29.3]
```

Then, I have another `List` of `Integers`:

```
[2,1,0]
```

These integers refer to the index by which I want to reorder the first list. So, I would like to reorder the first list to be:

```
[29.3,26.2,50.0]
```

I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: The example doesn't make it clear what the goal is, specifically if the indices are for the source list or for the destination list. If the indices are for the source list, a reordered copy would be dst[i] = src[index[i]], or if the indices are for the destination list (sometimes called a "rank"), a reordered copy would be dst[index[i]] = src[i]. A clearer example would reorder all 3 (or more) elements, rather than leave the middle element in place. Based on the accepted answer, it appears the the indices are for the source list.

Comment: For source based indices, it is possible to do this in place and with O(n) time complexity, as seen in this [prior thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775994/reorder-array-according-to-given-index/46776144#46776144), but the list of indices also get "sorted".

Comment: @rcgldr +1 - Great point. I've updated my post.

Comment: @James - with the updated answer, the integer list is a ranking list, where a reordered copy would be dst[rank[i]] = src[i]. I don't know Java that well, but it appears that Matt Goodrich's answer handles the other situation, dst[i] = src[index[i]]. An in-place version of reorder by rank is possible as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reorder-a-array-according-to-given-indexes), but it also sorts the ranks.

Comment: @James - just a comment here, what process would create such a ranking list as shown in the updated example, and how common would this be? For example, if an array of indices 0 to n-1 are sorted according to another array of elements, you end up with "source" based indices: dst[i] = src[sorted_index[i]] (this is one way of sorting multiple arrays according to one of the arrays). If a rank is desired, the sorted indices can be converted into ranks rank[sorted_index[i]] = i, but it doesn't seem as common as source based indexing.

Comment: @rcgldr - I have a method that implements the Large Remainder Method (LRM). The method takes a list of `BigDecimal`s and sorts them according to the largest remainder. It records (in another list, the `Integer` list) the original order of the list. After LRM rounding of the `BigDecimal` values, it needs to return a `BigDecimal` list of the LRM rounded values in order corresponding to the original `BigDecimal` list passed into the method.

Comment: @James - thanks for the explanation. So the sequence here is to sort the original array along with an array of indices to produce an array of ranks used to restore the original array. An alternative would be to leave the original array unmodified and only sort the indices according to largest remainder, but that could be slower due to random accessing of the big decimal (on my system, the trade off occurs when the element being sorted, in this case big decimal, is a size somewhere between 128 and 256 bytes if using a merge sort.

Comment: @regldr +1 Thanks for that alternative. That will will work great in my case. I'm dealing with a small array (<40). After some testing, performance doesn't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Original Solution

Let the first list of `BigDecimal` be called `decList` and the second list of `Integer` be called `intList`.

```
intList.stream().map(decList::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This takes each value of the second list and uses it as the index for accessing the value of the first list. These are then collected into a new `List<BigDecimal>`.

## (Edit) Examining Efficiency with `LinkedList`s

This is food for thought and the **solution above will normally suffice**.

#### TLDR

The only place `LinkedList`s will hurt my original solution is when the "values list" (the `List` with `BigDecimals` in this case) is a `LinkedList`.

#### Reasoning for this Testing

Since `get` on `ArrayList`s is `O(1)`, but `get` on `LinkedList`s is `O(N)`, there may be alternate, faster solutions.

I wanted to examine if using a solution with `Iterator` would be faster for `LinkedList`s. I read through all kinds of Javadocs and **couldn't find if running `linkedList.stream().map(..)` would use `.iterator` for `LinkedList`s instead of calling `get`**. Therefore I decided to time an actual test.

#### Test Cases

1. Test the original solution above with streaming and mapping, using `ArrayList`s.
2. Test the original solution above with streaming and mapping, using `LinkedList`s.
3. Test a solution using an explicit `.iterator` and `LinkedList`s.
4. Test the original solution above with streaming and mapping, using an `ArrayList` for the indexes and a `LinkedList` for the values.
5. Test the original solution above with streaming and mapping, using an `LinkedList` for the indexes and a `LinkedList` for the values.

#### Test Results

```
ArrayList Implementation:
Duration: 70 milliseconds
Duration: 15 milliseconds
Duration: 16 milliseconds
Duration: 15 milliseconds
Duration: 15 milliseconds
Average duration: 26 milliseconds

LinkedList Implementation with Stream and Map:
Duration: 1359 milliseconds
Duration: 1387 milliseconds
Duration: 1309 milliseconds
Duration: 1302 milliseconds
Duration: 1304 milliseconds
Average duration: 1332 milliseconds

LinkedList Implementation with Iterator:
Duration: 2806 milliseconds
Duration: 2173 milliseconds
Duration: 1305 milliseconds
Duration: 1305 milliseconds
Duration: 1305 milliseconds
Average duration: 1778 milliseconds

Mix test case #4:
Duration: 1281 milliseconds
Duration: 1278 milliseconds
Duration: 1278 milliseconds
Duration: 1278 milliseconds
Duration: 1278 milliseconds
Average duration: 1278 milliseconds

Mix test case #5:
Duration: 13 milliseconds
Duration: 7 milliseconds
Duration: 7 milliseconds
Duration: 7 milliseconds
Duration: 7 milliseconds
Average duration: 8 milliseconds
```

#### Conclusions

- My original solution is much faster for `ArrayList`s than `LinkedList`s, due to `O(N)` vs `O(N^2)`.
- It would seem **`stream`s already use `iterator`s, or similar enhancements to account for the `get` efficiency difference**. This is apparent through the similarity between test cases 2 and 3.
- `LinkedList`s only affect the efficiency when they contain the value in this algorithm, due to the iterator optimization with streams. Notice how test case #5 is just as fast as only using `ArrayList`s, despite how it uses a `LinkedList` for the indexes.

#### Source for Efficiency Testing

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testArrayListImplementation();
    testLinkedListImplementation();
    testCaseFourMixed();
    testCaseFiveMixed();
  }

  static void testArrayListImplementation() {
    List<BigDecimal> bigDecList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    List<Integer> ndxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("ArrayList Implementation:");
    timeListImplementation(bigDecList, ndxList, false);
  }

  static void testLinkedListImplementation() {
    List<BigDecimal> bigDecList = new LinkedList<BigDecimal>();
    List<Integer> ndxList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("LinkedList Implementation with Stream and Map:");
    timeListImplementation(bigDecList, ndxList, false);

    System.out.println("LinkedList Implementation with Iterator:");
    timeListImplementation(bigDecList, ndxList, true);
  }

  static void testCaseFourMixed() {
    //Test case 4
    List<BigDecimal> bigDecList = new LinkedList<BigDecimal>();
    List<Integer> ndxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Mix test case #4:");
    timeListImplementation(bigDecList, ndxList, false);
  }

  static void testCaseFiveMixed() {
    //Test case 5
    List<BigDecimal> bigDecList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    List<Integer> ndxList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Mix test case #5:");
    timeListImplementation(bigDecList, ndxList, false);
  }

  static void timeListImplementation(List<BigDecimal> bigDecList, List<Integer> ndxList, boolean useIterator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      bigDecList.add(new BigDecimal(123.4));
      ndxList.add((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
    }

    long totalDuration = 0;

    for (int linkedTrial = 0; linkedTrial < 5; linkedTrial++) {
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();

      for (int numComputations = 0; numComputations < 100; numComputations++) {
        if (useIterator) {
          Iterator<Integer> ndxIter = ndxList.iterator();
          List<BigDecimal> specializedList = new LinkedList<BigDecimal>();
          while (ndxIter.hasNext()) {
            specializedList.add(bigDecList.get(ndxIter.next()));
          }
        } else {
          List<BigDecimal> specializedList = ndxList.stream().map(bigDecList::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
      }

      long endTime = System.nanoTime();
      long duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000; //milliseconds

      System.out.println("Duration: " + duration + " milliseconds");
      totalDuration += duration;
    }
    System.out.println("Average duration: " + (totalDuration / 5) + " milliseconds");
  }
}
```

Comment: Anything better than O(N^2) ?

Comment: It's actually O(N)... if it's an `ArrayList`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner is correct, the get method of an ArrayList (assumed here) is constant time `O(1)` and the stream is `O(N)` to map each element. Collectors.toList() gets complex as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858497/java-collectors-tolist-complexity, but we'll need it regardless of the algorithm.

Comment: The question was against `List`. What if you have no knowledge about the implementation ?

Comment: @AndreiAmarfii you would need specific solutions per implementation of `List`. `ArrayList` is by far the most common, so it was assumed here.

Comment: Or let's assume that you have a well known `LinkedList`. In such case one way is to put the `LinkedList` into a `ArrayList` and after sorting put it back. However this will hit the memory . I'm wondering if there is a better .way than this one.

Comment: @Andrei It doesn't make any sense to have a list of indices to access a `LinkedList`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner if only software where driven by common sense... :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you could probably sort these by indexes: `Comparator<Integer> comp = Ordering.explicit(List.of(2, 1, 0));

        List<Integer> list = List.of(123, 456, 789);
        List<Integer> newOrder = list.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> list.indexOf(x), comp))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` but it's way too late for me to actually give this a thought about `Big O`

Comment: @AndreiAmarfii another approach would be to sort by indexes (see previous comment), but since it's sorts, it should be less efficient than this answer

Comment: @Eugene it's O(N^2) because of list.indexOf, or maybe worse, i.e. O(N^2logN)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thank you, I admit I am still not good at this, computing the Big O for some algorithm.

Comment: I spent quite a while studying the effects of LinkedLists with my solution and added edits. I'd be interested in feedback.

Comment: @Eugene if the list is an ArrayList, then yes, because ArrayList.get is O(1) and you are performing N gets. If it's a LinkedList, then no, because LinkedList.get is O(N), and doing N gets would yield O(N^2). In general, sorting algorithms are O(NlogN), though I'm not sure about TimSort, which is used in the JDK. However, the code in your comment is issuing a list.indexOf call, which is O(N), *inside* the comparator. If the code inside the comparator is O(1), then the sort algorithm is O(NlogN), but with the list.indexOf call, I believe it would take O(N^2logN) to sort the whole stream.

Comment: @Eugene Or maybe it's still O(NlogN) if list.indexOf is called log(N) times instead of N, which depends on TimSort implementation. In any case, the code of this answer has better performance.

Comment: @MattGoodrich Congrats on the edit. You really spent some good time crafting it. Your tests show what we already knew: LinkedList.get is O(N), hence the solution that uses it sucks. You've also shown that streams don't use get(i) to supply elements, though the implementation is based on Spliterator rather than Iterator. Though your tests show a valid effort, maybe you should read about JMH and how to do a correct micro benchmark (search the question here on SO). It will enlighten you and you'll surely learn about the factors that could invalidate a test such as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner. I'll read about JMH and micro benchmarking. I was looking for quick, approximate results (demonstrating the order) using a familiar method, but I'll use your method in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the first thing would be to access the values in BigDecimal. 
Using the properties in BigDecimal given by the parent class.

```
**Loop the values**:
  BigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.get(List.get(int index)));

**Delete the amount of times that the loop ran:** 
  BigDecimal.remove(int index);
```

The object of BigDecimal should be reorder into the correct values base on index. However, the function is running at 2N.